# Django - Heroku push succeeds but getting AttributeError (module has no attribute)

Tags: python, django, heroku, attributeerror

I pushed my web app to Heroku and it built / deployed fine, but I get this error when I access it:

```
AttributeError at /
module 'wakemeup.models' has no attribute 'environment'
Exception Location: /app/lib/UsefulFunctions/googleUtils.py in <module>, line 16
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.10
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

It works fine locally, so my first thought was the `PYTHONPATH`, but it seems to be similar locally:

```
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ravioli\\projects\\dcp',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**Directory structure** (simplified)

[image]

**googleUtils.py** (simplified)

```
import os
import sys
import io
import copy
from urllib.error import HTTPError

# Import - Google
from google.oauth2 import service_account
...

# Import - Application
from lib.UsefulFunctions.dataUtils import get_setting
import wakemeup.models.environment as env

class GoogleDriveManager():
 ...
```

I originally had the `import wakemeup.models.environment as env` line as `from ... import` but that was giving me a circular dependency error, so I changed it and it works fine locally.  Not sure if that has to do with it.

How can I fix this so it works on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the import statement and it works now:

```py
from wakemeup import models
# import wakemeup.models.environment as env # original
```

Maybe there was another module named `environment` that Heroku uses, not sure.